# git получить список измененных файлов в коммите

Tags: git

На Windows есть локальный репозиторий Git.
Получал список измененных файлов в коммите следующей командой:

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT %CommitId% | tar -rf CommitId/%CommitId%.tar -T -
```

Где %CommitId% - это номер коммита, подставляется в Bat файле вручную.
Но вот я сделал, коммит изменений новых и решил получить архив файлов измененных - и теперь эта команда делает пустой архив. Не пойму в чем проблема ?
Подскажите как получить список измененных файлов определенного коммита (не важно последний он или нет), никак не могу осилить доку по гиту...

---

Дополняю, понял в чем-дело.. оказывается diff-tree получает изменения только в рамках ветки текущей, т.е. в случае со слиянием одной ветки в другую, в конечном итоге команда ничего не выводит, пока не будет каких-то изменение после слияния, и уже их можно будет получить в архив.
Для таких вещей есть команда просто diff, но там нет фильтра --diff-filter=ACMRT - что просто удручает...
Вопрос по прежнему актуален, т.к. хочется кошерное решение с одной командой и указанием 1 ИД коммита.

Comment: Не могу сказать точно, но что выводит git show -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT %CommitId%

Comment: `но там нет фильтра --diff-filter=ACMRT` — у команды diff есть **опция** `--diff-filter`. согласно истории коммитов, уже где-то шесть лет. если ваша версия программы git старее, имеет смысл установить более новую.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис выводит не полный список файлов, по сравнению с тем, что на самомо деле замерджилось.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, версия 2,22,0
Да вы правы !!! Я просто не в том месте указывал фильтр, поэтому это чудо не работало. Сначала OPTIONS, а потом уже надо было в конце SHA. Хотя странно, оно с работало и так... видимо криворукость поправилась маленько ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Остановился на варианте, который использую в бат-файле следующего содержания:

```
::echo off
set "SHA1=%1%"
set "SHA2=%2%"
set "SHALevel=~1"
if "%SHA2%"=="" (set "IdCommand=%SHA1%%SHALevel% %SHA1%") else (set "IdCommand=%SHA2% %SHA1%")
git diff --diff-filter=ACMRT --name-only %IdCommand% | tar -rf CommitId/%SHA1%.tar -T -
::pause
```

Используя SurceTree, создал пользовательскую команду и выгружаю изменения любого выбранного коммита в архив. Можно будет покумекать и на случай выбора нескольких коммитов, но это уже другая история..